# How to download pdf from azure blob storage with @azure/storage-blob

Tags: angular, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have API endpoint which gives me response with file url already with generated SAS token like `https://{{url}}5521.pdf?{{sastoken}}`. I am using `@azure/storage-blob` so I am trying something like this:

```
  public downloadAzureInvoice(): void {
    const orderId = this._order$.value.id;
    this.httpClient
      .get(this.apiUrlsProvider.apiUrl('orders/' + orderId + '/invoice_pdf_url'))
      .pipe(
        switchMap((data: any) => {
          const blobClient = new BlockBlobClient(data.invoice_pdf_url);
          return from(blobClient.download());
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

result is

[image]

but i have no idea hot to save it as PDF on hard drive.

Comment: Ok, i solved it. Additionaly i had to use FileSaver library.

Comment: Answer the question with a complete explanation

Comment: Hi @obaram if you solved your issue kindly post as an answer so that it will be helpful for other members who can encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use FileSaver library.

```
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';

  public downloadAzureInvoice(order: OrderEntity): any {
    this.httpClient
      .get(this.apiUrlsProvider.apiUrl(`orders/${order?.id}/invoice_pdf_url`))
      .pipe(
        switchMap((data: any) => {
          const blobClient = new BlockBlobClient(data.invoice_pdf_url);
          return from(blobClient.download());
        }),
        switchMap((data) => from(data.blobBody)),
        map((data) => FileSaver.saveAs(data, `${order.orderInvoice.number}.pdf`))
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```